# Why my fan speed is constant in fedora?

Tags: fedora, kernel, temperature, fan

I am just using fedora for almost 3 months on this laptop, and just noticed that my fan speed is not increasing even the temp is so high, I can't remember if it is already happening before the upgrade to kernel 4.12.

My average temp is around 38C, then I tried to use `stress -c 4` then I already reached 65C but the fan speed still the same, so I stop the `stress`.

I am a bit worried about this, please help me about this. On my previous MS Windows setup, the fan speed will ramp up if the temp is high and will completely stop when my temp is around average.

Thanks.

Edit: System specs

Aspire 4750z (quite old but with good maintenance)

CPU: i5 2430M (2 cores 4 threads)

Mem: 12gb

Storag: 128gb ssd, 500gb rusty.

Graphics: Integrated

Comment: Does `top` show you utilizing a lot of CPU? What are you system specs on the laptop? Please attach this info to your original post.

Comment: @Patrick at normal usage no, I am just using around  5% to 20% average. but I tried to execute `stress` command to stress the cpu to the max.

Comment: @Patrick BTW at gaming I am having high CPU utilization and reaching more or less 50C.

Comment: Have you put the system through a suspend/resume cycle before this happens, or does it happen even without suspend?

Comment: I didn't put it on suspend/resume cycle.